# HTTP connection to a HTTPS URL, is it secure?

Tags: rest, http, https, integration

Our system only has a HTTP Smart Service feature to connect to external system.

If the target external system we are trying to connect to is “https” then does that make it secure?

We are just putting an authentication token in the header.

Comment: What is an HTTP Smart Service? Because depending on how you're connecting, you almost definitely need HTTPS.

Comment: Define "secure"

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not.

There are many factors that make it secure vs insecure. HTTPS is just one piece of the puzzle. If HTTPS used it *might* mean that the connection is encrypted and no one can eavesdrop, but being 'secure' can mean a lot more things.

Comment: Hi Evert. Could you explain more?

Comment: @AnotherDev I might be able to, but I would need a more specific question. You're assuming I know which part you need to know more about ;)

Comment: The endpoint of the external system I'm calling is https://... would my http request be encoded in SSL at least? Or some type of security?